# Possible Vectorization using If Statements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement, vector, vectorization, conditional-statements

Suppose I have the following column vectors as

```
res1 = -0.81              res2 =  0.61
        0.1                      -0.4
       -0.91                      0.62
        0.2                      -0.56
        0.63                     -0.72
```

and I have two fixed constant `D = 0.5`. Now suppose an element of `res1` is called `X` and an element of `res2` is called `Y`. I have the following conditions

```
if (X > D && Y < -D)
     output = 1
elseif (X < -D && Y > D)
     output = -1
else
     output = 0
end
```

My question is this:

Is it possible to "vectorize" these conditions to iterate over the entire vectors `res1` and `res2`, such that my output vector would give  **(for example)** :

```
 output = -1
           0
          -1
           0
           1
```

?

I know I can do it via a loop, but I would prefer to avoid it since these vectors are actually quite large (>10000). I have attempted to use logical indexing, but to no avail (unless I'm implementing it wrong).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How is the first element of the result -1 when given your second condition of (X < -D && Y > D) and  X  = 0.81,  Y = -0.28, D = 0.5 then (0.81 < -0.5) && (-0.28 > 0.5) would return false? Please fix this...

Comment: It's why I added the bold (for example) because I know the output does not match the conditions applied to the two vectors. I just wanted to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: I'll quickly fix it! I'm just at work and was in a bit of rush.

Comment: Fixed example vectors to match output vector!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`logical arrays`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html#btjk576-1)** to replace the conditional statements and scale them with appropriate scaling factors for the final output -

```
%// Logical arrays corresponding to the IF and ELSEIF conditional statements
case1 = res1>D & res2<-D
case2 = res1<-D & res2>D

%// Get the final output after multiplying each case with the
%// scaling factors 1 and -1 respectively. 
%// The default value of `zero` for the ELSE part is automatically taken 
%// care of because we are using logical array of ones and zeros anyway
output = case1 + -1*case2 %// or simply case1 - case2
```

---

Sample run -

```
>> res1
res1 =
   -0.8100
    0.1000
   -0.9100
    0.2000
    0.6300
>> res2
res2 =
    0.6100
   -0.4000
    0.6200
   -0.5600
   -0.7200
>> output
output =
    -1
     0
    -1
     0
     1
```